# Cocos2D LevelSVG iPhone Parallax Background, Adding during runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Guys. I'm writing a scrolling shooter game that has a very large Background image chopped up into smaller images to make it more manageable. Right now it is setup so when the GameNode is init'd. A big long list of Images are added to the ParallaxNode and it is added to the Game.
    I thought I might save a lot of memory if I only kept one or two loaded into memory and swap them out as the Hero Character moves through the level. The problem is I can't seem to create a parallax background in another method that's called later. No errors it just doesn't show and seems to be the same code. Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you verify whether there are any error messages in the console like "can't find image x"? - or, did you made sure to add the background as child to the scene that is running? -even more, as has been 1 year, did you solve the problem? Could you EDIT the question if so and provide some insight to how :)? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I created the parallax layer having four layers in it and added it to the level layer which is extending from GameNode.
If you can post some code, that may help.